# Untangling some SQL please?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to migrate an Access Query to a SQL Server View.  I've got the Select portion done, but I'm getting a "Syntax Error near '='" when I paste in this FROM and WHERE.   I'm hoping one of you can identify that error (as I'm unable to)

```
FROM   facility 
   INNER JOIN ((dbo.elmscoursereportlisttableaulink 
                INNER JOIN dbo.userlearningneeds 
                        ON dbo.elmscoursereportlisttableaulink.[item id] = 
                           dbo.userlearningneeds.[item id]) 
               INNER JOIN roster 
                       ON dbo.userlearningneeds.[user id] = 
              roster.[user id]) 
           ON facility.[abbr] = roster.[routing symbol] 
WHERE  ( ( ( dbo.elmscoursereportlisttableaulink.report ) = true ) 
     AND ( ( dbo.elmscoursereportlisttableaulink.active ) = true ) 
     AND ( ( 
   ( dbo.userlearningneeds.[revision number] = 
             dbo.elmscoursereportlisttableaulink.[revision number] ) 
    OR ( ( dbo.userlearningneeds.[revision number] ) IS NULL 
         AND ( dbo.elmscoursereportlisttableaulink.[revision number] ) IS 
             NULL 
       ) 
           ) = true ) );
```

Comment: Yikes. Carriage returns and indenting go a long way; you should try them some time. Do you scroll horizontally when managing your code in Management Studio, Visual Studio, etc.? Also, `=True` is not valid in SQL Server - there is no boolean data type. Are these `BIT` columns? If so, try changing `=True` to `=1` and `=False` to `=0`. If they're strings, use `='True'` or `='False'`.

Comment: SQL Server does not have a BOOLEAN type, = True will not work.

Comment: Egads Access promotes horrible, horrible syntax for its joins.

Comment: I don't see much to simplify here, except those weird parenthesis. Are they adding anything useful?

Comment: Access doesn't *promote* that syntax, it actually *writes* it.

Comment: Yes....organizationally a mess that I could've improved w/ returns & indenting.   I learned from your post that there's no "Boolean" type in SQL, and that was a kicker.....2 were bits (so made them 1) and I just dumped the last true all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by formatting that SQL :) http://poorsql.com/

The last '= True' looks suspicious - try removing that and changing the other true's to 1's.

Comment: These were exactly the moves I made and the syntax was made valid.